# fly-out for left naviation (for lists and libraries)

Tags: navigation

How to implement fly out for Lists or libraries that are on the left navigation? I have over 40 libraries and 20 lists and the left navigation looks messy and scrolling issue. Is there a way to implement fly out for lists and libraries? If yes, how? Any help or link would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here.

http://www.manageprojectsonsharepoint.com/blog/2011/04/26/enable-flyout-menus-on-the-quick-launch/

with the exception of I just want to change the background color of the fly out area and not the other menus background. The proposed style in the head changes background of the all the menu.

I put following code in the Head section in order get a different background and border on the fly out menu.

```
<style type="text/css">
     /* flyout left navigation look and feel */     
    .s4-ql li.dynamic a
    {       
        background: #EF5EU7;
        border:1px solid #EF5EU9;
    }
    </style>
```